# Use define as arguments for define C(++)

Tags: c++, macros

I see myself stumbling over a little thing, where I need a macro *inside another macro*. Now, this is not a big problem, if you would use it in the actual declaration. However, I'd like to use it inside the arguments list.

Let me give an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define ARGUMENTS first_name, middle_name, last_name
#define GREET(ARGUMENTS) "Hello " << first_name << " " << middle_name << " " << last_name

int main() {
    std::cout << GREET("Stack", "Over", "flow") << std::endl;
}
```

If I were to compile this with g++ 5.2.1, I get this error:

```
test.cpp:8:44: error: macro "GREET" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1
  std::cout << GREET("Stack", "Over", "flow") << std::endl;
```

Is it possible to do something like this, and if so: how?

---

**NB:** I know that I could easily use a function in this example, but using a function in my actual program is hard, so I'd rather use macros for that.

---

As Olaf requested in the comments, here is my actual code:

```
#define B0123 b0, b1, b2, b3

#define fill(A, B0123)  A[0]=b0; A[1]=b1; A[2]=b2; A[3]=b3;
#define comp(A, B0123)  (A[0]==b0 && A[1]==b1 && A[2]==b2 && A[3]==b3)

#define transferarr(dir, index, data)  bytes = libusb_control_transfer( handle, dir, 64, 0, index, data, 4, 0 );

#define transfer(dir, index, B0123)  fill(data, B0123); transferarr(dir, index, data);

#define T_OUT 0x40

#define transferout(index, B0123) transfer(T_OUT, index, B0123)

#define STATE_ONE 0xcc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8f
#define STATE_TWO 0xcd, 0x20, 0x00, 0x10

transferout(32800, STATE_ONE);
transferout(32800, STATE_TWO);
```

Comment: @LogicStuff Whoops, my mistake. Let me edit this example to make this clear

Comment: Please do not use macros to obfuscate coding. Actually, in you example typedefs/(inline) functions are much more transparent.

Comment: How do you want to use `NAMETYPE` macro in `GREET` macro? In your example you can just omit `NAMETYPE`. If you want to create a variable then use `#define GREET(a) "Hello " << NAMETYPE(a)`.

Comment: @DieterLücking In this example, that's the case yes. In my actual program, I want to take in different types, and pass them to another function:

`#define ARGS b0,b1,b2,b3
#define SEND(ARGS) send_message(CLIENT, ARGS)`

Comment: Have you checked to see if [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) does what you need already?

Comment: @KurtStutsman No, I didn't. Could you give an example on how I would use that?

Comment: macro argument names are not expanded. It would be a nightmare if they did, by the way.

Comment: As you already stated, the example is nonsense, thus any answer will likely not help with the actual problem. Please state the original problem; there might be a better way. Chances are this is an XY-problem.

Comment: Your example demonstrates well enough what you would like to do, but it is unilluminating about why you want to do it.  Since you *cannot* do specifically what you asked, we'll need a clearer understanding of your larger objective to tell you more than "don't do that" or "expand it manually".

Comment: Looks like variadic templates are wanted but the OP didn't state the problem clearly.

Comment: Your extensive usage of macros is insane. It becomes a 'meta' language nobody understands (variadic template are peanuts, compared to your preprocessor usage)

Comment: Why don't you rewrite your actual code using functions with array arguments like `void fill(int A[], char b[])` and so on?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking for, but for your actual use case present, you simply don't use another macro (which actually is parsed as the argument name for `GREET()`), but declare parameters as needed:

```
// Nope: #define ARGUMENTS first_name, middle_name, last_name
#define GREET(first_name, middle_name, last_name) "Hello " << first_name << " " << middle_name << " " << last_name
           // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Remember that the C-preprocessor just provides a single pass text replacement processing for macros.

Comment: Thanks!  It does indeed work, but I have several macros which use the same arguments (And they're lenghty to not confuse me), so I'd rather duplicate them. I suppose this is bad practice, but is there any way to do this easily?

Comment: You can't use a macro to define common arguments in other macros.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but macros simply do not work that way.  You can't define one macro's arguments in terms of another macro.  You have to write the code like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define GREET(first_name, middle_name, last_name) "Hello " << first_name << " " << middle_name << " " << last_name

int main() {
    std::cout << GREET("Stack", "Over", "flow") << std::endl;
}
```

To do what you are asking, you would have to do something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define GREET(%MYARGUMENTS%) "Hello " << first_name << " " << middle_name << " " << last_name

int main() {
    std::cout << GREET("Stack", "Over", "flow") << std::endl;
}
```

And then *preprocess* the code file using an outside tool that can replace `%MYARGUMENTS%` with your desired argument names prior to then compiling the resulting code.